# Make simple_form require an answer before submitting

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I am writing a rails app and using simple form for forms.  I have a form that has a user select answers to a question in the form of radio buttons.  However, the form currently allows the user to submit an answer without choosing an option, even if I put requires true in the simple_form.  Anyone have any idea how to actually require an answer first?

```
<%= simple_form_for @question do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.association :answer, as: :radio_buttons, label_method: :name, required: true %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation for answers in your question model, I'm assuming question has_many answers, see below:

```
Class Question
  has_many :answers
  validates_presence_of :answers
end
```

Here's a link to the documentation for `validates_presence_of`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of

Also in your form, it should be `f.association :answers`